# Analytical solution of driven damped oscillator with aperiodic conditions using DSolve from Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, physics, dsolve

I derived a solution for a driven damped oscillator using the DSolve functionality of Wolfram Mathematica. I chose the following Ansatz:

```
DSolve[{
   0 == -Fmax (1 - Cos[t]) + k x[t] +
   d Derivative[1][x][t] +
   m Derivative[2][x][t],
   x[0] == xStart, x'[0] == vStart}, x[t], t]
```

Mathematica is able to solve this analytically and I can derive solutions if I pass parameters to the variables.

Anyhow, the derived solution fails at the moment, the given parameters for mass (m), spring constant (k) and dampening (d) fulfill the condition for aperiodic behavior

```
d=2*Sqrt[m*k]
```

due to the fact, that a division by zero occurs. The overall solution is given by a big fraction with a denominator containing the following factor

```
Sqrt[d^2 - 4 k m]
```

This factor becomes zero in case aperiodic conditions occur which leads to a devision by zero.

Now the fun starts ...
I case I pass the aperiodic conditions before giving the system to DSolve:

```
DSolve[{
    0 == -Fmax (1 - Cos[t]) + k x[t] + 
    2 Sqrt[k m] Derivative[1][x][t] +
    m Derivative[2][x][t],
    x[0] == xStart, x'[0] == vStart}, x[t], t]
```

DSolve easily derives a working solution without dividing by zero.

It seems to me, as Mathematica is simplifying the more general solution, in a way that I can't use the aperiodic conditions anymore, even though there is a working solution for that case. My question is, can I somehow tell DSolve, to take into account the aperiodic conditions?

Sure, I can workaround the problem with Piecewise[], but for further calculations a general solution without Piecewise[] would be more suitable.

Thanks in advance for you time and help,

Greetings
Tschibi

Comment: I fixed some unbalanced parentheses and other formatting issues. Please check that its correct.

Comment: you can show the first form reduces to the second in the limit `d->2*Sqrt[m*k]`. Given the complexity of the expressions anyway I think you might as well just carry around the two forms and consider the special case as needed.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I considered a separated solution, but unfortunately this is only a partial solution for a bigger problem and I was hoping to get around a more complicated overall model. 

I tried to find out in what way you can influence DSolve in finding a solution beside "Assumptions" and "Method -> "Holonomic" ". Last one gives a working solution, but it is not suitable later within my calculations.

Your approach by using the limit is interesting. Maybe with that I can build a less complicated workaround.